# Which God/Goddess blessings are needed to learn astrology?

Tags: gods, astrology

I googled this question, and found that Bhrigu maharshi had written a book on astrology. But , I couldn't find which god blessings are required.

If anyone knows, Answer it.

`which god/goddess blessings are needed to learn Astrology?`

I want to do japam to gain the blessings before I start learning Astrology.

Comment: Usually Lord Ganesha is considered as the presiding deity for Astrology. You can search about this on Google.

Comment: Thanks for a perfect answer. Agree. Deleted my post.

Comment: Surya, Brahmaa, Saraswati (Medha) + Guru mantra (Paraashara/Vedavyaasa etc)